# How to add a footer in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki, footer

I have been trying to add a custom MediaWiki footer to my Game's Wiki and it is becoming a challenge. I have tried using 2 extensions that don't work and there is no footer.php or a place to add footer items in the LocalSettings. Obviously it must be somewhere or how is it displaying in the first place.

Any help?

Comment: The usual way to extend MediaWiki is to find an appropriate [hook](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks) and then inject/ modify/ delete something. Have you tried [Extension:PageNotice](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:PageNotice)? It [makes use of](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-PageNotice/blob/1d786a3175280c5e5119a545ae23e8acbca4d733/PageNotice.hooks.php#L54) the ArticleViewFooter hook, which might or might not sound promising.

Comment: I will have a look now. Thanks

Comment: Have you seen [Manual:Footer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Footer)?